# Cancel an answer when filling a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

Suppose that I, as an user, have to fill a Google Form. On a certain multiple-choice question, I choose the answer `yes`. Then, I recognize that I'm not sure it is the right one, so I want to cancel it. Is it possible? I'm unable to undo my choice.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, once you select an option on a multiple-choice questions the "only" way to return to the previous state (no option selected) is to start againg to filling up the form, meaning open again the orignal form link.

You could try to "hack" the form view by editing the DOM but nowadays this might not be a single tasks as the forms code is automatically optimized for performance not for readability. In order to do this you have to know use the web browser developer tools (you could try to right click the option then select Inspect, the dev tools will be openend showing the corresponding DOM element)